# How do I generate a combined .ll file from makefile or configure file?

Tags: makefile, clang, llvm, configure, llvm-ir

I wrote a module pass to generate a call graph. I want to generate call graph which would consist of all the functions like the functions in the user code as well as the functions in the libraries.

To be more specific, I am working with binutils 2.26     https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.26.tar.gz

I want to generate the call graph for 'objdump'. The code of the objdump would call some functions in the  library 'libiberty' these called functions in the library can call more internal functions inside the library.

I want a call graph which will include all such functions.

One way to do is that I can emit llvm code for all the files in the library as well as the user code in separate .ll files. And then finally combine them using llvm-link.
But this may fail if there are dependencies here and there. So can I do this systematically by making some changes in **configure file** or **makefile** without disturbing any dependencies.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One trick that could work here is [LLVM LTO](http://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html).

Try to use the following exports:

```
export CFLAGS=-flto
export CXXLAGS=-flto
export CPPLAGS=-flto
```

And the run your build as usual.
You should have normal binary as an output, along with a bunch of *.o files, which are not object files, but LLVM bitcode files.

Please, be aware that this approach depends on a particular build system being used.

Comment: It's not compiling, giving undefined reference error. Also it says plugin needed to handle lto object.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, should 'just work.' Anyways, this is the only 'flexible' approach I am aware of. Also, check your artefacts, linking is happening after compilation, so you probably have all the bitcode files in place.